# React fetch call status no content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I've tried this piece of code:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/signin", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "this-can-be-anything"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password
  })
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

It's a try to see if everything is good, if I try on Postman to call http://localhost:5000/api/signin everything work and here too but I don't get anything back. I get on network tab a call that get me the data I want, and another from the line I call the fetch with status 204.

No content, why?

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the promise returned by `response.json()`, so your promise chain is broken and `undefined` is given as argument to the last function.

Add the `return` keyword and it will work as expected.

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/signin", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "this-can-be-anything"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password
  })
})
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because you are not returning anything from

```
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  response.json();
})
```

If you add curly braces to an arrow function; then you need to add an explicit return. So change it to either:

```
.then(() => response.json())
```

or

```
.then(() => {
  return response.json();
})
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to return the `Promise` returned by `.json()`

This can be cleaned up a bit using the modern `ES7` feature of `async/await` avoiding the ubiquitous callback hell

```
const loginUser = async () => {

  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/signin", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "this-can-be-anything"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    })
  })

  const data = await response.json();

  console.log('[data]', data);

  return data;
}
```